# How to output a list a certain way with write?

Tags: prolog

I have a predicate `numbers/3`, that takes two numbers as the input and generates all the numbers in between them as a list. Now I want to output this list in a certain way, for example:

```
?- niceList(1,5).
1
2
3
4
5
.
```

I know I have to write a recursive clause to make this happen, but I'm stuck on how to do it.
So far, this is what I tried:

```
niceList(N1, N2):-
  numbers(N1, N2, [H|T]),
  write(H), nl,
  numbers(N1, N2, [T]).
```

The idea is to take the list, write down the Head and then continue with the Tail, which becomes the new [H|T]. What I wrote is incorrect however, as it only prints the Head and then returns False.

I would appreciate any help!

Answer (score 2):

After you print the current head, you have to recursively call `niceList` with the next number in the list (let's call it `NH` for next head) as the first argument.

Something like:

```
niceList(N1, N2):-
  numbers(N1, N2, [H|[NH|_]]),
  write(H), nl,
  niceList(NH, N2).
```

Note that it doesn't print to the last number inclusively.

#### Later edit:

Based on @lurker's comment below, I added a base case which prints to the last number inclusively and returns success.

```
niceList(N1, N2):-
  numlist(N1, N2, [H|[NH|_]]),
  write(H), nl,
  niceList(NH, N2),
  !.

niceList(_, N):- write(N).
```

Sample output:

```
?- niceList(1,5).
1
2
3
4
5
true.
```

Comment: Also you can use the built-in `numlist` instead of `numbers`.

Comment: And if you want it to succeed (not fail) you'd include a suitable base case.

Answer (score 0):

In case if you are running Swi-Prolog, you can use forall/2 predicate combined with between/3:

```
niceList(N1, N2) :-
    forall(
        between(N1, N2, N),
        format('~w~n', [N])
    ).
```

forall works as follows: for each solution of the predicate given as the first argument, execute the second argument. In our case, for each number N found to be between N1 and N2, execute format/3 (that is, print it to console).